# How to add background image in css?

Tags: css

I want to add background image in my css code but it's not loading.
How to change or add background image in css please help
I'm written css code in notpad++

Comment: Put your code here!!

Answer (score 4):

```
.Your class name {

background-image: url("your image url");

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: 100% 100%;

float: left;

width: auto;

}
```

Please try Above type of code in your css section.

Answer (score 0):

you can add that as this.

if you have id

```
#yourid{
   background-image: url("your image url(EX:imge.jpg)");


}
```

if you have class

```
.yourclass_name{
background-image: url("your image url(EX:imge.jpg)");

}
```

you can use background function also...if you add background css function,you should have to change width and height

```
    .yourclass_name {
     background: url("img_tree.png") no-repeat;
height:500px or give to precentage(30% like that);
width:1000px or give to precentage (70%);
    }
```

Comment: /* Here is my code still not working */                                                             .bd {
background-image: C:\Users\dell\Desktop\New folder("pic.jpg");
 background-color:#cccccc;
}

Comment: give height and width.then try again

Comment: check your background-image path

Answer (score 0):

This is the path u should specify, The way to copy the path is to go the directory where the image is present, then copy path there.

```
body { background-image:url("C:\1.jpg");
```

Comment: Do one thing, put the image in the same folder where html file is present. Then no need to specify path. Try it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an image as background-image in CSS, there are two ways of doing it:-

1. If you want to add an image from the internet then, you can use 
   `background-image: url("your image url");`

example:

```
background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQms3mJIPu3jlPy8b8cOmRg69qurCA82EBDofx6jaK11cUM6u4w");
```

2. If you want to add an image from your pc, then you should write the image path i.e.,
   `background-image: url("your image path");`

example:

```
background-image: url("C:\Users\Vimalendu Shekhar\Downloads\image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

#idname{
background-image: url("your image url");

}