# How do I fix this code for html background

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="background-image"></div>
    </body>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .background-image {
            background-image: url('./C:\Users\viraj\Downloads\html\Mountains.jfif');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height: 100vh;
        }    
    </style>
</html>
```

Whenever I run this code on my browser(Chrome) my background image won't show up. I don't know how to fix it so if anyone knows how to fix it, please tell me.

Comment: Try changing `\ ` to `/` ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add background image in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170310/how-to-add-background-image-in-css)

Comment: The daily "Why doesn't my image show?" question.

Comment: Also, the leading **`./`** won't work. For a local file you might want to add `file://` instead of the regular `https://`. While `/` (slashes) are the required characters to use, browsers will likely accept `\\` (back-slashes).

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with this line:

```css
background-image: url('./C:\Users\viraj\Downloads\html\Mountains.jfif');
```

1. `./` at the beginning of the url specifies a relative path, so the browser will look for the file in same directory in which your html file resides. You however need to omit `./` so that the browser will use the absolute path.
2. You need to escape the backslashes in the URL like this: '\\'

So the correct style would look like this:

```css
background-image: url('C:\\Users\\viraj\\Downloads\\html\\Mountains.jfif');
```

Answer (score 1):

use this instead

```
background-image: url('C:\\Users\viraj\Downloads\html\Mountains.jfif');
```

it would be better if you save image in same file where your index.html style.css are
and then use reference address for background

```
.background-image {
        background-image: url('\Mountains.jfif');
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100vh;
```

}

for more refer to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this `background-image: url('C:\Users\viraj\Downloads\html\Mountains.jfif');`

Answer (score 0):

one of pecularity about file path in windows and mac is that in mac each of folder are seprated by a `/`[forwardslash] whereas on windows they seprated by a `\` backslash as you notice when we are writing code  we **care about that we can just write it as `/`[forward slash] and making sure that we have the root**

solution:

```css
There are two issues with this line:

background-image: url('C:/Users/viraj/Downloads/html/Mountains.jfif');
```